# Add ajax return value to selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to insert a value from my database to select box using it's **ID**. this my code for that

```
<select id="branch_name">
    <option value="0">Select branch Name</option>
</select>

$.ajax({
    url : 'get_savac_member_data.php',
    method : "POST",
    data : data,
    success : function(response){
        // window.location.replace("items_insert_form.php");
        var res = response;
        var segments = response.split(",");

        $("#brnch_name").val(segments[17].trim()); 

    }
});
```

My value has returned successfully. But, it shows nothing to my select box. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `#branch_name` ...

Comment: You have to use $.each function, search about how to insert into a select

Comment: You can create options html in php file and replace it into select box directly from js. `$("#brnch_name").val(response);` Or you can create html in js and then replace in to select box..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proper html to `select`. Something like

```
 for(var key in obj) {
        html += "<option value=" + key  + ">" +obj[key] + "</option>"
    }
```

And then `$("#brnch_name").html(html)`.

For this example, I assume you are getting response in `json` format

Answer (score 0):

Use $.each like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'get_savac_member_data.php',
    method : "POST",
    data : data,
    success : function(response){
    // window.location.replace("items_insert_form.php");
    var res = response;
    var segments = response.split(",");
    $.each(res, function (key, value) {
        $("#brnch_name").append($("<option></option>").val(segments[key].trim());
        }); 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
  $("#brnch_name").empty(); //clear the drop down box
  for (var i=0;i<segments.length;i++)
  {
     html="<option value=\""+segments[i]+"\">"+segments[i]+"</option>";
     $("#brnch_name").append(html);    
  }
```

Comment: Please select 1 of these solutions as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the response and append to select with `$('#branch_name').append($('<option>', { value: item.value, text : item.text }));` here value is the value of option and text is text to be displayed on dorpdown.

```js
$.ajax({
    url : 'get_savac_member_data.php',
    method : "POST",
    data : data,
    success : function(response){
    // window.location.replace("items_insert_form.php");
    var res = response;
    var segments = response.split(",");
    $.each(res, function (i, item) {
        $('#branch_name').append($('<option>', { 
            value: item.value,
            text : item.text 
         }));
    });
});
```

```html
<select id="branch_name">
  <option value="0">Select branch Name</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each branch names from response and append the same as individual `<option>` tags. However you have already got several solutions for the same, while mine uses simple string replace.

```js
/* this is only relevant script */
var response = 'Branch 1,Branch 2,Branch 3,Branch 4';
$('<option>' + response.replace(/\,/g, '</option><option>') + '</option>').appendTo('#branch_name');
/*in-case you wish to show a default selection */
$('#branch_name').prop('selectedIndex', 3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="branch_name"><option value="0">Select branch Name</option></select>
```